# Web Control Panel for Multiple Students W/Login

Tags: networking, server, webserver, html, .htaccess

My teacher is trying to make a control panel for all of her students so they can use WordPress, code their website, etc.

She has a server in her class so that they can use that for the web server. The problem is that she needs to have multiple students access it at once. (like 000webhost)

What I want is a **free** (if I have to I can do a paid application) application/service that when you type in the IP address for the server, it will prompt the student with a username and password. (that the teacher/I set) Then it will bring up a control panel for them, and included in the control panel I want an online FTP access. And last, I want it to whenever they do the IP/"student name"(/ root www directory for a student) so they can see the website.

The whole point of this is to teach the students about HTML, **and** things like .htaccess. (because I know that you can't use .htaccess in Brackets or another "Live Preview" application)

If there is no hope we might have to just have to use a web server on all of the student's computers.

I am the one setting up the server, and the teacher doesn't care about me messing around with it.

The server is running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Many thanks in advance.

Ciao,
Landon

Comment: What does the control panel control?  If you're using Wordpress it included its own management and editing system.  A simple bash script that creates the Apache config, downloads Wordpress and installs seems like a good start

Comment: I don't mean the WordPress control panel, but a web host's control panel with an admin and users for the website. The WordPress control panel is something that comes with it after you install all of the files.

Comment: try cPanel.
From wiki: cPanel is a Linux-based web hosting control panel that provides a graphical interface and automation tools designed to simplify the process of hosting a web site.

Answer (score 0):

host more than one website on a single Linux machine use "virtual Hosting"

## two Types of Virtual Host

### Name Based Virtual Hosting:

several domains/websites on a single machine with a single IP.

### IP Based Virtual Hosting:

assign a separate IP for each domain on a single server

## How to Setup

**Setup Name Based Virtual Host**
But, before creating a virtual host, you need to create a directory where you will keep all your website’s files. So, create directories for these two virtual hosts under `/var/www/html` folder. Please remember /var/www/html will be your default Document Root in the Apache virtual configuration.

```
mkdir /var/www/html/example1.com/
mkdir /var/www/html/example2.com/
```

To set up Name based virtual hosting you must need to tell Apache to which IP you will be using to receive the Apache requests for all the websites or domain names. We can do this with NameVirtualHost directive. Open Apache main configuration file with VI editor.

```
 vi /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Search for `NameVirtualHost` and *uncomment* this line by removing the # sign in front of it.
`NameVirtualHost`
Next add the IP with possible in which you want to receive Apache requests. After the changes, your file should look like this:

```
NameVirtualHost 192.168.0.100:80
```

setup Virtual host sections for your domains,Here in this example, We are setting up virtual host sections for two domains

```
www.example1.com
www.example2.com
```

Add the following two virtual directives at the bottom of the file. Save and close the file.

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.0.100:80>
    ServerAdmin     webmaster@example1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example1.com
    ServerName www.example1.com 
    ErrorLog      logs/www.example1.com-error_log 
    CustomLog logs/www.example1.com-access_log     common 
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80> 
     ServerAdmin webmaster@example2.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example2.com
     ServerName www.example2.com 
     ErrorLog logs/www.example2.com-error_log 
     CustomLog logs/www.example2.com-access_log common 
 </VirtualHost>
```

You are free to add as many directives you want to add in your domains virtual host section.
please check the syntax of files with following command.

```
httpd -t  Syntax OK
```

If syntax is OK. Please restart your Web server and add it to chkconfig to make your web server start in runlevel 3 and 5 at the boot time only.

```
service httpd restart
chkconfig --level 35 httpd on
```

now it's time to create your html content in any of example directories or setup wordpress in any of them.
Once you’re done with it, you can test the setup by accessing both the domains in a browser.

```
http://www.example1.com
http://www.example2.com
```

Comment: Is there a web control panel that the students can use? **With** online FTP? For example GoDaddy, or 000Webhost.

Comment: not exactly,but You will achieve the goals you mentioned in your question with Virtual Hosting. for example you can install Wordpress for each students in her virtual host and on wordpress install ftp plugin and etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use Vesta Control Panel ([link](https://vestacp.com/))

**Introduction**

The Vesta Control Panel is a free, open source website control panel with website, email, database, and DNS functionalities built in.

**Install**

Supports - Ubuntu 12.04-15.10

## Download installation script

```
sudo curl -O http://vestacp.com/pub/vst-install.sh
```

## Run it

```
sudo bash vst-install.sh
```

Comment: Thats what we have right now, there is not a lot of support for Vesta.

Comment: Oh, well there are alternatives.  ispconfig is free, then there are plenty paid... cpanel, directadmin, interworx, etc..  You'll either need to admin the system and create the setup you want, or choose a control panel and hopefully modify to your liking.  I don't know how else to answer your question.

Comment: Yes, DirectAdmin is perfect, just how do I host the website on the local machine?

Comment: "DirectAdmin can run on a LAN/NAT, many of our clients do it, even though it's not officially supported."  The following URL should assist you in installing it using local IPs.
http://www.directadmin.com/lan.shtml

Comment: I just don't get how in a real life situation you can tie the DirectAdmin to a domain name. Maybe I can put it in a subdomain of localhost?

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure directadmin installs Bind for DNS, so as long as your clients point to the server for DNS, you could make any domain name.  Otherwise, subdomains off a working primary domain will work.  Once again, if you're using it locally, you'll have to tweak the environment.

Comment: Any documentation for this?

Comment: It shouldn't change outside what's on the directadmin install page.  Your clients dns servers for its network connection can point to directadmin, and regardless what you're using for sitenames will resolve to its correct address.  You really could use studentname.com.  It will only work on that network of course.  Directadmin will believe whatever you tell it to believe.